# Converting SSAS connection to NativeQuery with SQL expression in PowerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas

I am attempting to convert a SSAS connection in PBI into a NativeQuery wrapper so that I can set an SQL statement to refine the connection data volume.  I am getting syntax errors no matter what I try, here is my current attempt and what the SSAS connection successfully generates.  Any advice on what to change?  (error text posted as well)

SSAS connection (working):

```
let
    Source = AnalysisServices.Database("XXX.com", "Pro", [TypedMeasureColumns=true, Implementation="2.0"]){[Id="Pro"]}[Data]{[Id="Pro"]}[Data],
    #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(Source,
        {
            {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "[Contacts]", {"[Contacts].[ContactType].[ContactType]"}, {"Contacts.ContactType"}}
        })
in
    #"Added Items"
```

Native Query (not working):

```
let
    Source = Value.NativeQuery(AnalysisServices.Database("XXX.com", "Pro", [Implementation="2.0"]), 
         "SELECT 
         ContactType
         FROM Pro.Contacts
         "
         , null, null
)
in
    Source
```

ERROR:

> DataSource.Error: AnalysisServices: Query (2, 10) The 'ContactType'
> column cannot be found in the 'Contacts' table.